# make does not compiling source files

Tags: makefile

i have tried to write makefile for my project and wrote this:

```
SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = obj

CX = g++
CC = gcc
SRCS = 
OBJS = 

LDFLAGS = 
CFLAGS = -Wall

.PHONY = main

main: SRCS += $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp
main: OBJS += $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o 
main: $(OBJS)
    $(CX) -o release $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) 

$(OBJ_DIR)/main.o: $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp
    $(CX) -o $@ -c $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

but when i call `make main` output is:

```
g++ -o main obj/main.o  
g++: error: obj/main.o: No such file or directory
g++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:17: main] Error 1
```

main.cpp is hello world

P.S. sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Rule Definition" subsection of section [3.7 How make Reads a Makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles) in the manual of GNU Make describes how parts of a rule are expanded:

> ```
> immediate: immediate ; deferred
>     deferred
> ```

In your Makefile the line

```
main: $(OBJS)
```

corresponds to

```
immediate: immediate
```

part in the documentation.  Therefore Make sees rule with the recipe like this:

```
main:
    $(CX) -o release $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

In other words, what you're trying to do shouldn't work. Don't use [target-specific variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific) to define dependencies.

Comment: now it works, but how could i change dependencies for target?

Comment: @xiaomifanboy, just use different variables for different targets: `main.SRCS`, `other.SRCS`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

just re-define OBJS and SRCS without the `main:` prefix:

```
SRC_DIR = src
OBJ_DIR = obj

CX = g++
CC = gcc
SRCS = 
OBJS = 

LDFLAGS = 
CFLAGS = -Wall

.PHONY = main

# NOTE THE DIFFERENCE HERE: no 'main:'
SRCS += $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp
OBJS += $(OBJ_DIR)/main.o 
main: $(OBJS)
    $(CX) -o release $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) 

$(OBJ_DIR)/main.o: $(SRC_DIR)/main.cpp
    $(CX) -o $@ -c $^ $(CFLAGS)
```